# java.lang.ClassCastException with YouTube API for Android

Tags: android, api, youtube, lg

I'm receiving the following error when I try to play videos using the YouTube API.  The video will initialize and show the thumbnail, but when you click play, the app crashes.

This only happens on the Android LG P925 device.  The video will actually play on other devices.

Here's the error:

```
03-04 20:20:49.140  10473-10496/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: YouTubePlayer.MediaPlayerThread
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.b.a.cx cannot be cast to android.view.S3DSurfaceHolder
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.notifyS3DChanged(MediaPlayer.java:2102)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:938)
        at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.as.e(SourceFile:163)
        at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.ax.b(SourceFile:38)
        at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.bd.handleMessage(SourceFile:689)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
        03-04 20:20:51.164      232-286/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ newRssi value = -55
        03-04 20:20:52.890      139-231/? E/CrayonGraph-Base﹕ [setState] OMX.VisualOn.FileSource, state=0x1, error=0x80001012
        03-04 20:20:52.890      139-231/? E/CrayonGraph-Base﹕ [setState] OMX.VisualOn.FileSource, state=0x1, error=0x80001012
        03-04 20:20:52.898    139-10509/? E/CrayonGraph-Base﹕ [setState] OMX.VisualOn.FileSource, state=0x1, error=0x80001012
        03-04 20:20:52.992  10293-10293/com.nickprofitt.YoutubeListing E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
        at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.jar.a.eo.surfaceDestroyed(SourceFile:236)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:581)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:245)
        at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:9905)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2266)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2266)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3561)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3509)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.h(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e.onServiceDisconnected(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1076)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1090)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4516)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.b.a.be.a(SourceFile:221)
        at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.jar.a.eo.surfaceDestroyed(SourceFile:233)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:581)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:245)
        at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:9905)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2266)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2266)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3561)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3509)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.h(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e.onServiceDisconnected(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1076)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1090)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4516)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the code:

```
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored)
{
    ytPlayer = player;

    player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
            | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
            | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);

    if(!wasRestored)
    {
        player.cueVideo(FeedAccount.getInstance().getVideoIDArray()[FeedAccount.getInstance().getSelectionIndex()]);
        final YouTubePlayer mPlayer = player;
        ytPlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFullscreen(boolean fullsize) {
                if (fullsize) {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                } else
                {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }
            }
        });

        player.setPlaybackEventListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaying() {
                if(!wasPlaying)
                {
                    wasPlaying = true;
                    mPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPaused() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopped() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekTo(int i) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get a fix for this crash ?

Comment: @thedarkpassenger No, but I didn't worry about it because that phone is really old.  I just increased the minSdkVersion so we didn't have to account for that device.

Answer (score 0):

use loadVideo(video_id) instead of cueVideo(video_id), this helps me